# Intersection of two disconnected sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have prove or disprove that the intersection of two disconnected sets is a disconnected set. I tried finding a counter example on the real line with the usual metric,but I can't seem to find a counter example.I want to proceed to prove that it is the case that the intersection is indeed a disconnected set,but want to know if I might be wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Huh?  $A = (0,2) \cup (4,6)$ and $B=(4,6) \cup (8,10)$ and $A\cap B = (4,6)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\{0,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$. They are both disconnected sets of $\mathbb R$ and yet their intersection $\{1\}$ is connected.

Comment: Aah that seems rather elegant.I assume that a singleton is therefore  an interval since that is how we characterize connected sets on the real line?

Comment: Yes a singleton is a particular type of interval as $\{y\}$ equals $\{x \in \mathbb R : y \leq x \leq y\} = [y,y]$. Note that the counter-example I have provided can be generalized in the following way: if $A$, $B$, $C$ are pairwise disjoint non-empty intervals, then $U = A \cup B$ and $V = B \cup C$ are both disconnected with connected intersection $U \cap V = B$.

Comment: Thank you so much @DodoDuQuercy!

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P} \cup \{0\}$ (where $\mathbb{P}$ are the irrationals in $\Bbb R$, usual topology) are both totally disconnected and yet their intersection is $\{0\}$ and thus connected.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $C$ is any connected set.  Say $C=(0,1)$. Let $\beta \supset C$ and $\alpha \supset C$ so that $\beta\cap \alpha=C$.  Say $\beta = (-\infty,1)$ and $\alpha = (0, \infty)$.

Let $C \subset A \subset \alpha; C\subset B \subset \beta$ so so that $A$ and $B$ are disconnected.  Say $B = (-2,-1)\cup (0, 1)$ and $A = (0,1)\cup (2,3)$.

That's your counterexample.